# Strange Sublime error 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2

So I'm using Sublime Text 2 to run a python script after IDLE gave me some really weird issues.  I had it working earlier, everything was working perfectly.  I had accidentally deleted my entire path when switching it to accept the python (like every other response you'll see to a question like this) but I needed my old paths back so I was trying to fix that problem, and eventually got some of them back, and tacked python onto the end of it.  When I tried to run the program again, it failed giving me an Error 2.  So I saved my path this time, and only used python (like a I had done before I added all my paths back in) and it's still spitting out an Error 2.  I've done everything I can think of.

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\\Python27\\PyPart']]
[dir:  C:\Python27]
[path: C:\Python27]
[Finished]
```

As you can see, Python in in the path, it's the exact same path I had when it worked...  If anyone has more experience with this than I and could shed some light on it, that would be amazing.  Please and thank you.

Comment: Since you're using a Windows, `python` might need to be `python.exe`?

Comment: I know this exact path worked earlier.  I had copied it to a sticky note before adding some of my older paths in case something like this happened.  After it gave me this the first time, I put the path I had into sticky notes and moved the previous one to the path by itself which is why there's not a list of paths there.